# Would you explain the function of "with" in the sentence below:

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, prepositional-phrases

> Using case-control, cohort, and case-crossover analysis, the investigators found that tramadol increased the risk of hospitalization for hypoglycemia by more than three-fold, **with** the risk particularly elevated in the first 30 days of treatment.

In my opinion, "with" is just a preposition. And after preposition we only need a noun or noun phrase. But in this sentence, it seems that "with" has the function of conjunction. Is it true? would you explain it for me, please!

Comment: "With" is a preposition and preps freely take clausal complements, both finite and non-finite (like yours). Here, the PP is an adjunct (grammatically optional).

Answer (score 1):

Here, "with" means "accompanied by". There is an implied "being" between "risk" and "particularly elevated". That is, the sentence is equivalent to:

> Using case-control, cohort, and case-crossover analysis, the investigators found that tramadol increased the risk of hospitalization for hypoglycemia by more than three-fold, **accompanied by** the risk **being** particularly elevated in the first 30 days of treatment.

Though, of course, the original is more idiomatic and flows better.